# Map columns of a data frame using a string

Tags: r

I have a 2x5 data frame with row names and column names as specified below:

```
test <- matrix(NA,nrow=2,ncol=5)
test[1,] = c(2,3,6,8,9)
test[2,] = c(5,3,2,7,8)
colnames(test) = c('aa','bb','cc','dd','ee')
rownames(test) = c('first','second')
test = data.frame(test)
```

I would like to map the columns of the data frame to the format specified by this vector:

```
test2 = c('ee','cc','dd','bb','aa')
```

Does anyone know how I can do that?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Whats' your desired output? You wont to reorder the columns? I.e., is that what you want `test[,test2]`?

Comment: If you wanna change the column order, then it would be `test2 = test[, c('ee','cc','dd','bb','aa')]`.

Comment: Yeah I wanted to change the column order, that works perfectly thanks!!